# Are there best practices for naming SOAP interface methods and variables?

Tags: web-services, soap, naming, naming-conventions

In .NET, Microsoft has guidelines for naming classes, members, etc. when developing class libraries. Other languages may also have best practices how to name classes, how/if to use some notations.

Now SOAP is a protocol that can be used to possibly communicate across language boundaries. Are there best practices how to name functions, variable names, etc.? Or should I use whatever my language (if at all) uses? Or when I'm generating a SOAP interface via tools (e.g. WCF service contracts), should I use whatever the tool produces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be no official W3C naming convention for service method names.

Some commonly used guidelines:

- Method names should clearly indicate what they do from the client's point of view
- Use different method names instead of overloading
- In general, PascalCasing seems to be favored (no underscores). For .Net, follow the .Net naming conventions for normal methods.

You may also find [this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/christomkins/entry/my_thoughts_on_service_naming) from Oracle useful.

Comment: Blog post link is broken now. Here's the post captured on the Internet Archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150919045942/http://blogs.oracle.com/christomkins/entry/my_thoughts_on_service_naming